# Swift segmentation fault 11 due to variable scope

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segmentation-fault, xcode6

The following code caused the IDE in Xcode to fail, and swiftc throws segmentation fault (11):

```
func testDeviceWillNotify()
{
    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("Will be ready.")

    class FooMock: Foo
    {
        func accessoryDidConnect()
        {
            expectation.fulfill()
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

If I comment out the `expectation.fulfill()` everything is works correctly. I have also tried `expectation!` and `expectation?` but any reference to `expectation` caused Xcode to crash.

Using Xcode 6.1 (6A1052d) and its extremely frustrating. Does anyone know a way around this bug? Even writing the test another way will have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how it your code suppose to work because the inner class have to automatically capture variables in the method scope.

This is a workaround

```
class FooMock: Foo
{
    var accessoryDidConnectFunc : (Void -> Void)?
    func accessoryDidConnect()
    {
        accessoryDidConnectFunc ?()
    }
}

func testDeviceWillNotify()
{
    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("Will be ready.")

    let foo = FooMock()
    foo.accessoryDidConnectFunc = { expectation.fulfill() }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: That works. But now some other total unrelated code is causing swiftc to crash with exit code 1 with "Global is external, but doesn't have external or weak linkage!", oh well...